# Using in-url basic authentication in firefox

Tags: http, firefox

I'm using launching firefox from the command line in a script to get snapshots of pages. These pages have basic http authentication. When using:

```
firefox http://user:pass@url.com
```

Either a dialog appears, or authentication doesn't work at all.

Is there any option to make firefox open the page without showing the dialog?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use basic authentication with jQuery and Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/use-basic-authentication-with-jquery-and-ajax)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open `about:config` page in firefox. Create a new Integer key (right-click->New->Integer):
`network.http.phishy-userpass-length` with value `255`.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, read more here: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.phishy-userpass-length

Answer (score 5):

For me it makes all the difference of the world adding the slash at the end of the context root. Without the slash, the popup opens. With the slash it logs in as expected.

`http://username:password@mysite.com/login`  --> does not work
`http://username:password@mysite.com/login/` --> works

firefox version 19.0