# How to bypass firefox authentication box when open an url from linux command line?

Tags: linux, firefox, command-line, qunit

We have a QUnit test page for a website. And, we would like to make it a regression test that can be started automatically from linux command line. But, if we start the firefox from command line, it will popup a window saying "Authentication Required" even though I have saved the username and password. Is there a way to bypass it? We have tried to add the url as a trusted site using "about:config", but it didn't help.

Also, is there a way to test website automatically starting from command line? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using in-url basic authentication in firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848287/using-in-url-basic-authentication-in-firefox)